# iPhone - Showing a simple xib without custom controller

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, xib, modalviewcontroller

I'd like to show a modal about view, with some text and just a toolbar into which there would be a simple button that closes the view.

The text, the toolbar and its button are into a xib.

Is there a way to show this view (modally) and being able to dismiss it when "OK" is touched, without having to write a custom controller (AboutBoxController) to handle it ?

If it's possible, could you show me what code you would use to do this ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to have a controller for your modal view? As far as I know, if you want to present a modal view, you have to present a controller which displays its view.

Comment: @Jamie : It's to reduce useless files in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a controller that just dismisses itself when OK is touched is effortless, so I don't really see the point. It would probably be faster to just write that controller than writing this question.

I guess if you really don't want to write that controller, you could let some other controller respond to the button action. However, you'd be writing at least the same amount of code and you'd be doing it in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes of course, but the point is that I don't like to have useless files in my project.